# My ear is open Or, My ears are open - Which one?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

My ear is open to listen you.. Or, My ears are open to listen you..

Which one is right?

Comment: More idiomatically: _I’m all ears_.

Comment: I used to work with someone who was fond of saying, rather facetiously, "I'm listening with both ears."

Comment: Both alternatives are clearly ungrammatical. Impossible to choose.

Comment: Thanks Janus and Michael for new sentence of similar meaning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each would be a figurative use of *ear* to refer to the act of listening, and in such figurative use both the singular and the plural can be used.

To describe ears as open isn't very common, though it has at least one precedent

> My ear is open like a greedy shark,
>
> To catch the tunings of a voice divine. - John Keats

But to say your "ears are open" would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "my ears are open", to mirror the phrase "my eyes are open".

If you say "my ear os open", you suggest that your're only half listening....

@Janus: perfect!

Comment: Thanks.. ZZMike!... I thought the same way too.. if "my eyes are open" why not "my ears are open" :)